# how to apply map function when list contain elements of class objects?

Tags: python

Python 3.8

MRE:

If I want to apply some function to each element of a list I would do:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list(map(lambda x: x*2, lst))
```

I want to do the same thing when elements of lst are **class object** and want to run method for each class object. I could do this using for loop however curious to know if I could use map function as it is more efficient.

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def reset(self):
        self.value = 0

obj_lst = [test(1), test(2), test(3)]

# want to replace this with map function
for obj in obj_lst:
    obj.reset()
```

I've tried

```
map(lambda x:x.reset(), obj_lst)
```

however doesn't work.

Comment: return `self.value` after `self.value = 0` Because the output of the reset function is None by default and Lambda sets the output of the function

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA My expected output is to reset all test class objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return self.value` after `self.value = 0`  Because the output of the reset function is None by default and `map` function sets the output of the function

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def reset(self):
        self.value = 0
        # return self.value

    @classmethod
    def show(cls, obj_list: list):
        print([obj.value for obj in obj_list])


obj_lst = [Test(1), Test(2), Test(3)]

# print("before", obj_lst[0].value)
# want to replace this with map function
for obj in obj_lst:
    obj.reset()

Test.show(obj_list=obj_lst)
#
# print(list(map(lambda x: x.reset(), obj_lst)))
#
# print("after ", obj_lst[0].value)
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I don't want `reset method` to return anything however simply reset its object?

Comment: Your code is working properly and you can write a `@classmethod` that takes an `object_list` as input and displays the `values` inside it

Answer (score 1):

In your first example when you applied that function you gave back a result ! that's what returns from applying the function to individual items. But now, you just want to do something with items and not interested in what is getting back! the return value of your `reset` method is None. So in this way you just populate a list of Nones.

```
[None, None, None]
```

Your for loop is the best answer.

You could do it with `list(map())` or list comprehension but that won't give you efficiency except it returns a list of `None`s...

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def reset(self):
        self.value = 0

obj_lst = [test(1), test(2), test(3)]

[i.reset() for i in obj_lst]

print(obj_lst[0].value)   # 0
```

At least I didn't assign it so after the operation that list get garbage collected immediately. But again there is nothing wrong with your for loop.

Comment: Thanks! I know there is nothing wrong with for loop method, just want to know alternative methods if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to run the function `reset()` on every object and that function doesn't return any values, it would be better to go with the `for-loop` approach.

What `map()` does ? [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

> Return an iterator that applies function to every item of iterable.

Use `map()` when you have a function that returns some values and you need those values.

Answer (score 1):

**Just for loop is enough.Because your function return nothing.**

But if you really want to get instance of them, you have two solutions:

1. change the lambda function:

```
list(map(lambda x: x.reset() or x, obj_lst))

# [<__main__.test at 0x1103baa90>, <__main__.test at 0x1103bad30>, <__main__.test at 0x1103ba5b0>]
```

2. do `return self` in function `reset`

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def reset(self):
        self.value = 0
        return self

obj_lst = [test(1), test(2), test(3)]
list(map(lambda x: x.reset(), obj_lst))
# [<__main__.test at 0x1103baa90>, <__main__.test at 0x1103bad30>, <__main__.test at 0x1103ba5b0>]
```

---

And all these values have reseted to zero.

Comment: Thanks. why does reset happen when we wrap `map(lambda x: x.reset(), obj_lst)` with list?

Comment: @haneulkim it was an iterator before you convert it to list.....the operation wouldn't occur.